# Player Not Moving by AddForce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to create a room escape game, and I enter the code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float horizontalInput;
    [SerializeField] private float verticalInput;
    public float speed = 20.0f;
    // Declare a Rigidbody variable
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Get the Rigidbody component from the game object
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        // Create a force vector based on the input and speed
        Vector3 force = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput) * speed;
        // Apply the force to the Rigidbody
        rb.AddForce(force);
    }
}
```

This is my first and only code for now. I added the box collider on the camera so it can create a first-person view. I also added  rigidbodies to the room (floor, ceiling, and walls). The room have Mesh Collider on default. The player cannot move when I press play.

I tried to change the mass, kinematic option, and checked on the Constraints dropdown. I checked the gravity is on, `HorizontalInput` and `verticalInput` is working properly. I am sure the error is not on Rigidbody because I set the mass to 1. But I cannot figure out why the player can't move.

Comment: you need to ask yourself, knowing that the weight is in kg, how much force are you actually adding? I mean a 100kg cube isnt going to move muich if I had 20kg of force if theres friction etc